# Discord.js Searching for a user in an array is always returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to make a bot choose randomly from a list of players that reacted to a message and send the player it chooses, but it always sends undefined.

Here's the code for the randomizer.

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
const collector = giveawayMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: timeRemaining });
const reactionUsers = [];
giveawayMessage.react('');
collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '' && !user.bot) {
        for (let i = 0; i < reactionUsers.length; i++) {
            if (user === reactionUsers[i]) return;
        }
        reactionUsers.push(user);
    }
});
let chosenReaction;
for (let i = timeRemaining; i >= 0; i--) {
    delay(1000);
    timeRemaining--;
    numDays = Math.trunc(timeRemaining / 86400);
    numHours = Math.trunc((timeRemaining - (numDays * 86400)) / 3600);
    numMinutes = Math.trunc((timeRemaining - (numDays * 86400) - (numHours * 3600)) / 60);
    numSeconds = timeRemaining - (numDays * 86400) - (numHours * 3600) - (numMinutes * 60);
    timeRemainingFormatted = `${numDays}d ${numHours}h ${numMinutes}m ${numSeconds}s`;
    chosenReaction = Math.ceil(Math.random() * reactionUsers.length);
    embed = EmbedBuilder.from(embed).setFields({ name: 'Prize', value: `${interaction.options.getString('prize')}` }, { name: 'Time Remaining', value: `${timeRemainingFormatted}` });
    giveawayMessage.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
    if (timeRemaining <= 0 && i <= 0) {
        console.log('Done!');
        chosenReaction = Math.ceil(Math.random() * reactionUsers.length);
        embed = EmbedBuilder.from(embed).addFields({ name: 'Winner', value: `${reactionUsers[chosenReaction - 1]}` });
        giveawayMessage.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
    }

}
```

I tried making it choose on every iteration, expecting that the issue was that it stopped iterating before setting the variable, but it did not cause a noticable difference.

Comment: What does the `delay` function do and where does it come from? It may be blocking loop iterations - standard JavaScript does not support a synchronous sleep method.

Comment: @traktor The `delay` function just makes a timeout. It doesn't really impact the code and just makes it wait 1 second between iterations using `setTimeout()`

Comment: That won't be effective in a synchronous call: please edit to show the code in the question, thanks.

Comment: If the problem is with `delay`, I would expect  the loop to finish almost immediately, without actually taking  `timeRemaining` seconds to do so, and that  when choosing a winner (or on loop exit) the length of `reactionUsers` will be zero. Can you can confirm if either or both of these predictions are correct?

Comment: @traktor It does seem to take the full time to do it, but does it in chunks of about 5 iterations at a time. I can `reactionUsers` is 0 when it ends, as you said.

Comment: @traktor I think `delay()` was the issue. I posted an answer that solves the problems by using Discord's time notation instead of a loop because the loop really only mattered to decrement the remaining time and display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually doesn't require a loop to do, as Discord has a time notation that can do what I was using the loop for. Then you can just put what you need at the end in a `setTimeout(function())`

```
let embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('Giveaway')
    .setDescription(`${interaction.user} is hosting a giveaway.`)
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Prize', value: `${interaction.options.getString('prize')}` }, 
        { name: 'Ends', value: `<t:${endTime}:R>` },
const collector = giveawayMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: timeRemaining });
const reactionUsers = [];
giveawayMessage.react('');
collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '' && !user.bot) {
        for (let i = 0; i < reactionUsers.length; i++) {
            if (user === reactionUsers[i]) return;
        }
        reactionUsers.push(user);
        console.log(`${user} reacted with ${reaction.emoji.name}`);
    }
});
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Done!');
    const reactionChosen = Math.ceil(Math.random() * reactionUsers.length);
    embed = EmbedBuilder.from(embed)
        .addFields({ name: 'Winner', value: `${reactionUsers[reactionChosen - 1]}` });
    giveawayMessage.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
}, timeRemaining * 1000);
```